# Firefox not showing auth pop-up during www-authenticate negotiate

Tags: firefox, kerberos, spnego, www-authenticate

I have java app that authenticates users based on kerberos WWW-Authenticate Negotiate through browser. All Chromium-based ones behaves identically — sends NTLM ticket which is not supported in the app, gets 401 Unauthorized back, prompts for login/password and then sends the kerberos token. Firefox remains silent (blank page with no prompts) upon receiving 401 Unauthorized after NTLM attempt.

I can force Firefox to show prompt, but only with WWW-Authenticate Basic.

What I have already tried within Firefox:

- incognito firefox tab
- firefox safe mode
- network.auth.use-sspi true/false
- network.negotiate-auth.using-native-gsslib true/false
- setting up network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris with all sorts of uris
- setting up  network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris with all sorts of uris
- network.auth.force-generic-ntlm true/false
- network.auth.force-generic-ntlm-v1 true/false

thanks.